# The code isn't outputting, but it's running. [c]

Tags: c, debugging, runtime, output

**Code Function:** It's a Russian Peasant Multiplication calculator.
**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main(){
  int ier, product = 0, check, i = 1; //var to store numbers
  float cand; //Var to store decimal numbers

  while(i != 0){
    printf("\nInput only whole numbers!"); //Ask user for number to be multiplied
    printf("\nMultiplier: ");
    scanf("%d", &ier);
    printf("Multiplicand: ");
    scanf("%d", &cand);

    while(i != 0){
      if((ier == 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand == 0) || (ier == 0  && cand < 0) || (ier < 0 && cand == 0)){//Regulations for the code
        printf("Product: 0");
        printf("\n\nInput only whole numbers!");
        printf("\nMultiplier: ");
        scanf("%d", &ier);
        printf("Multiplicand: ");
        scanf("%d", &cand);
      }
      if((ier > 0 && cand > 0) || (ier < 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand < 0) || (ier < 0 && cand < 0)){
        break;
      }
      if(ier == 0 && cand == 0){//If user inputs 0 and 0, end code
        return 0;
      }
    }

    while(i != 0){
      if((ier < 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand < 0) || (ier < 0 && cand < 0)){//Regulations for the code
        printf("Values must not be negative");
        printf("\n\nInput only whole numbers!");
        printf("\nMultiplier: ");
        scanf("%d", &ier);
        printf("Multiplicand: ");
        scanf("%d", &cand);
      }
      if((ier > 0 && cand > 0) || (ier == 0  && cand > 0) || (ier > 0 && cand == 0) || (ier == 0  && cand < 0) || (ier < 0 && cand == 0)){
        break;
      }
      if(ier == 0 && cand == 0){//If user inputs 0 and 0, end code
        return 0;
      }
    }

    if(ier > 0 && cand > 0){
      printf("Calculating Product:");//It should print this, but it isn't for some reason.
      while(i != 0){
        if(fmod(cand, 2) != 0){
          if(fmod(cand, 1) != 0){
            product = product + floor(cand);
            cand = floor(cand);
            printf("%d \t%f", ier, cand);
          }
          else{
            product = product + cand;
            printf("%d \t%f", ier, cand);
          }
        }
        if(cand == 1){
          printf("Product: %d", product);
          break;
        }
        ier *= 2;
        cand /= 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:** When I run code and I input e.g 5 and 2, it keeps on running without outputting anything. I think the problem in the code is the `fmod()`. I'm only using `fmod` because you can't use the modulus operator `%` on float variables.
**Thing I have done:** I changed the fmod to the modulus operator `%` and made cand into an integer. That worked, but now I have a problem with the decimal since integers round decimal number. So I went back to `fmod`.
**Input:**

```
gcc version 4.6.3
Input only whole numbers!
Multiplier:  5
Multiplicand:  2
/*Runtime: infinite*/
```

**Output I want**

```
Multiplier: 57
Multiplicand: 86
Calculating product:
114 43
228 21    
912 5    
3648 1
Product: 4902
Multiplier: 48
Multiplicand: -36
Values must not be negative
Multiplier: 27
Multiplicand: 0
Product: 0
Multiplier: 0
Multiplicand: 0
```

**P.S:** It's my first time using `fmod` and `floor()`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138405/discussion-on-question-by-manav-dubey-streetsville-ss-the-code-isnt-outputti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your code, I found that you used the `scanf` function incorrectly.  In your code after the first `while` loop, you did the following:

```
while(i != 0){
    printf("\nInput only whole numbers!"); //Ask user for number to be multiplied
    printf("\nMultiplier: ");
    scanf("%d", &ier);
    printf("Multiplicand: ");
    scanf("%d", &cand);
```

If you look at the `scanf` above this sentence, you can see that you did (As @MartinR pointed out):

```
scanf("%d", &cand);
```

You need to change the code to following:

```
scanf("%f", &cand);
```

This will fix your infinite runtime. Also, @ABusyProgrammer may have written the response first(which is correct), he/she didn't read the post properly. *You* are using the `fmod` which requires a float. Therefore, you need to use the `scanf` that I written above. @ABusyProgrammer would only be correct if you are using the `%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code goes into an infinite loop is not because of the `fmod()` function, but rather because you have initialized `cand` as a `float` value, and not as an `int` value.  Changing `cand` to an `int` value allows the code to continue working to print out the result:

So, change:

```
float cand;
```

To:

```
int cand;
```

This at least prevents the code from hanging, and, just like @WeatherVane pointed, it also fixes a warning that your compiler should produce for the following line:

```
scanf("%d", &cand); // "cand" is a float, but your format specifier says that it is an int.
```

Comment: Which will also deal with the compiler warnings about `scanf("%d", &cand);` where `cand` was a `float`.

Comment: @WeatherVane True, I didn't notice that. Finding that it was the `float` that was causing that hang was hard enough. I'll update my post. Thanks for that point!

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer, read the post properly. The user is using the `fmod`, there it requires a float.